# Bcrypt Custom password configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

i am changing the password and then forwarding to /loginuser and redirect to users dashboard. i had secured this with httpbasic authentication since i am a beginner, I am using createNativeSQLQuery in hibernate and fetching the results from Database. Did I have to implement any UserDetailsService Interface Spring Security? My goal is to only achieve encrypting password and store it DB. the issue i am facing is, I had added a bean configuration such as,

```
@Bean
        public PasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(){
                @Override
                public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
                    return BCrypt.hashpw(rawPassword.toString(), BCrypt.gensalt(4));
                }
                @Override
                public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
                    return BCrypt.checkpw(rawPassword.toString(), encodedPassword);
                }
            };
        }
```

I don't know why its throwing this exception. should we hard-code the salt rounds?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid salt
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw(BCrypt.java:552) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt.checkpw(BCrypt.java:659) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.bootapp.FullTimeEquivalents.config.PasswordEncoderConfig$1.matches(PasswordEncoderConfig.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Did you make sure that you store encrypted one in the DB, not the plain text, and in the matches, have you called the function with the first argument a plain one and the second as an encoded one.

Comment: initially i store password as "password" in DB and try to change the password and encode using custom BcryptEncoder config in PasswordEncoderConfig Class, while trying to acheive this I am facing this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem because your encoded password has a length < 28, 
from spring sources:

```
if (saltLength < 28) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid salt");
}
```

how to fix that:

1. Increase salt rounds to 10
2. Try to set minimum password length to 4-5

I hope that helps.